# Opera makes scoped_dir* folders in the Downloads folder

Tags: windows-10, download, opera

When I download an executable file on Opera, and then launch the file via the Downloads menu, Opera generates a scoped_dir* folder with * being a bunch of random numbers. I can't figure out how to stop this behavior.

Comment: I think if you download to the same hard drive partition as the OS's temp folder, it won't create these scoped dirs. This means that you may be able to change the temp folder's location if you don't want to change the download folder's. Haven't tried this myself though so not putting this as an answer.